# Redis and HBase problem, need your experience

Tags: redis, nosql, hbase

For my exams I have to do many exercise in NoSQL database. I have no problem, at the moment, with MongoDB and Cassandra, but i'm unable to run Hbase and Redis.

I read that Redis is only for Unix System, is that true?

For hbase, I downloaded the .zip with hbase-2.2.4-bin from https://hbase.apache.org/downloads.html but I have a lot of 'missing .java class errors' when I try to run the `hbase shell` command.

can somebody explain me how to start from zero or post a guide that can help me step by step?

I forgot to tell you that i'm using windows 10, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis supports multiple operating system and multiple programming language across the platform. It's just that it was most tested and used on UNIX platform so far.

Please check the below link for your reference to run Redis on Windows.

[Download and install Redis on Windows](https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-8-1-and-previous-versions/)